# Formulario en una sola línea - CSS - Bootstrap 4 + Laravel

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

estoy desarrollando una listado de productos, que permite elegir un color y además una cantidad para agregarlo a un "carrito de pedidos online". Resulta que no encuentro la forma de darle los anchos que corresponden al input para poner la cantidad de unidades. La idea es que quede un campo más angosto, no tan ancho, y que el botón quede bien a la derecha del contenedor y que el input de la cantidad quede al lado del select del color... Alguien puede darme una mano para ver cómo ordenar esto ?, desde ya muchas gracias !!!

```
<form class="form-inline">
@csrf
<div class="col-md-5">
    @if(count($product->colors) > 0)
    <select class="form-control-sm" name="color_id" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Seleccione">
        <option selected>Color...</option>
        @foreach ($product->colors as $color)
            <option value="{{ $color->code }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @else
        <small class="text-danger">SIN COLORES DEFINIDOS - NO SE PUEDE GENERAR UN PEDIDO</small>
    @endif
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
         {{ Form::number('quantity', 0, ['class' => 'form-control-sm ml-auto', 'id' => 'discount', 'required', 'step' => 1, 'min' => 0]) }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
       @if ($product->stock === 'SIN STOCK')
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" name="button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg mr-2" disabled></i>Agregar</button>
       @else
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right" name="button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg mr-2"></i>Agregar</button>
       @endif
    </div>
    </form>
```

El limite del contenedor del formulario es el borde del boton "Agregar".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metiendo mano, encontré que el `form-control-sm` genera un descontrol en los controles y su adaptacion a las columnas de bootstrap. Asi que eliminando todo lo que sea esa especificacion, quedo como queria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]